# how to Refresh the Page after the f5 is Clicked in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a web site that have some information and actions in it.What is the best way to avoid duplicate record insertion on page refresh. Now when I enter data in web site and get parameters, and click the f5 button, the last data appears again while I want to see all textboxes null.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because the browser stores cache and history while loading the page. There can be different ways of this problem's solution:

**First**

before refreshing the page using `F5` make sure to clear the cache.

***ctrl + shift + delete  ->  clear cache***

**Second**

Make `autocomplete` property to disable.

Syntax:

```
<input autocomplete="on|off">
```

Follow this for more information.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: How can I use autocomplete property? Shall I use it in my load page?